# Geometric intuition behind the Uniform Boundedness Principle

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, functional-analysis, intuition

Is there a way to visualize why the Uniform Boundedness Principle should be true? I understand the statement of the theorem but I'm having a hard time seeing a picture of it in my head.

Answer (score 3):

You have a collection $(T_i)_{i\in I}$ of bounded operators, and $(e_j)_j$ a collection of directions. Given a direction, the "orbit" $\{T_ie_j,i\in I\}$ is bounded. This means that there is a bounded set $S_j$ such that applications of the bounded operators to $e_j$ cannot make you leave this set. If the space is "without holes", this was because the operators "had a bounded amplitude".

Comment: Could you please expand on the last part of this answer?